# CreateProcessW with EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT fails

Tags: windows, unicode, process

I have a situation where I need to start a process with unicode characters, and need to use EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT.  That combination seems to always fail.  Here's the simplest repo case.  TestFunctionA() works, while TestFunctionW() has the error:

```
void TestFunctionA()
{
    STARTUPINFOEXA startup_info = { 0 };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info = { 0 };

    std::string cmd("ping.exe");
    BOOL ret = CreateProcessA(NULL, (LPSTR)cmd.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, NULL, NULL, (LPSTARTUPINFOA) &startup_info, &process_info);
    if (!ret)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "Failed: code " << err << std::endl;
    }
}

void TestFunctionW()
{
    STARTUPINFOEXW startup_info = { 0 };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info = { 0 };

    std::wstring cmd(L"ping.exe");
    BOOL ret = CreateProcessW(NULL, (LPWSTR)cmd.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, NULL, NULL, (LPSTARTUPINFOW)&startup_info, &process_info);
    if (!ret)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "Failed: code " << err << std::endl;
    }
}
```

GetLastError in TestFunctionW return 87 (parameter is incorrect).

Does EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT only work with STARTUPINFOEXA?

Comment: You must specify the size of the STARTUPINFO data: `startup_info.cb = sizeof(startup_info);`

Comment: @joshpoley that should be `startup_info.StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(startup_info);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @joshpoley!

Had to add this:

`startup_info.StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(startup_info);`

Now both functions work

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `startup_info.lpAttributeList` should not be NULL either, since the whole purpose of using `STARTUPINFOEX` is to pass a *populated* `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST` to `CreateProcess()`.

Comment: Yes that's true - it my actual code that list was populated.  I just removed it for the minimal code to reproduce.